# Sending a variable to another page from a link created in a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I am trying to pass a PHP variable from a link created in a for each loop.

Here is the code on the page that generates the link and variable to send:

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$storeArray = array();

foreach($xmlDoc->product as $Product) {
echo "Name: " . $Product->name . ", ";
echo "Price: " . $Product->price . ", ";

$store = (string)$Product->store;

if (!array_key_exists($store, $storeArray)) {
$storeArray[$store] = "<a href='searchResults.php?storeSearch=<?php echo $store; ?>'>" .     
$store . "</a>";
}}

foreach ($storeArray as $store) {
echo $store . "<br>";
}
```

Here is the code on the page that receives the variable:
    $searchByStore = $_GET["storeSearch"];
    echo "Store search variable is: " . $searchByStore;

The searchByStore variable is not being echoed. Any advice?

Here is how this url appears in the browser:
    .../searchResults.php?storeSearch=%3C?php%20echo%20Best%20Buy;%20?%3E
Instead of the normal way, which is:
    .../searchResults.php?storeSearch=Best%20Buy

And here is the XML file:

```
<product type="Electronics">
<name> Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Lap top</name>
<price>599.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Hardware">
<name>Hand Saw</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<store>Lowes</store>
</product>

</products>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is wrong:

```
$storeArray[$store] = "<a href='searchResults.php?storeSearch=<?php echo $store; ?>'>" .     
$store . "</a>

";
```

change it to

```
$storeArray[$store] = "<a href='searchResults.php?storeSearch=".$store."'>".$store."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed PHP code inside PHP code:

```
$storeArray[$store] = "<a href='searchResults.php?storeSearch=<?php echo $store; ?>'>" .     
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It should be

```
$storeArray[$store] = "<a blah blah storeSearch=" . $store . ">";
```

or

```
$storeArray[$store] = "<a blah blah storeSearch={$store}>";
```